# Show series $\sum \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis

Show series $\sum \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}$

I know that somehow I am supposed to use the comparison test to show that this series diverges.

I tried several ideas in order to find a series that is smaller but i keep only finding convergent series smaller than this series.

$\sum \frac{1}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}$ is smaller but is convergent.

If $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ worked then this problem would be easier but I can't figure out how show that this is smaller when it seems to be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Use the limit comparison test with the harmonic series:

$$\frac{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac1n}=\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac n{n+1}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot\frac1e=\frac1e$$

and since the harmonic series diverges so does yours.

Comment: apparently its supposed to diverge by the limit comparison test but you do bring up a good point.

Comment: @DivVares Thank you. How with the limit comparison test? With what series do you compare it?

Comment: But if the general term converges to $\frac{1}{e}$ the series must diverge!

Comment: @gonthalo You're right. I forgot and thought I was working with the quotient test. Editing...or erasing, whatever the case be.

Answer (score 2):

Use equivalents:
$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac1{n+1}\cdot\frac1{\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^{\!n}}\sim_\infty\frac1e\cdot\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 2):

A more direct proof, using the more elementary "comparison test" (no need for the more advanced "limit" comparison test):

When discussing $e$, part of the discussion involves $(1+\frac 1 n)^{n+1}$ - it is shown that this is a decreasing sequence. This is all we need - then all the terms are $\le 4$, $4$ being the value of the first term. We DON'T need to know that this sequence converges to $e$, or anything else about it.

Now the general term of the series can also be written as:

$$\frac 1 n \cdot \frac 1 {(1+ \frac 1 n)^{n+1}} \ge \frac 1 n \cdot \frac 1 4$$

and you are done using the "usual" comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look for traces of $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{e}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so by the definition, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$
such that for all $n>N$,
$$\left\vert\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}-\frac{1}{e}\right\vert<\frac{1}{2e}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}>\frac{1}{2e}.$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\sum\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&>\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
+\frac{1}{2e}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1},
\end{align}
where $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges. Hence we conclude that
$\sum\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ diverges.